# Close votes review cue hangs - bug

Tags: bug, status-completed

When attempting to access the review cue for close votes,the cue hangs and errors out.

The error states - An error occurred when loading the review item, please try again.

I am able to open review cues on other sites.

Comment: It gives `500 Internal Server Error` at `http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/review/next-task/3` coming from `http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/close`.

Comment: I'd report this on Meta Stack Exchange, so as to give it more visibility.

Comment: It works when applying filter.

Comment: @nicael No need to repost this on meta.SE just to get more visibility. It is not a network problem and it is equally visible to the devs here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Are you sure it didn't happen anywhere else? Why did it happen there then?

Comment: @nicael The site is only a few hours old. It is likely a simple configuration issue. Think horses, not zebras <grin>.

Comment: The dev team is looking at this now.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed.  Let me know if you have any additional issues!

Comment: Works great, thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is still some small issue saying `Review item not found.` when going to `/review/close` (which requesting `/review/next-task/3`) and it helps  only when going Next.

Comment: I responded here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272867/what-does-review-item-not-found-mean